# Changes in the child custom theme are not visible in the front end

Tags: layout, custom, footer, parent-child-theme, default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="about-us" before="search-term-popular-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">About Us</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">about-us</argument>
            <argument name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="target" xsi:type="string">_blank</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Link" name="account_link" group="navigation-sections">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Account</argument>
            <argument name="use_force" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<!-- Account links -->]]></argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Can anybody help I am trying it since yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your code with this one, hope it will help you.

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="about-us">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">About Us</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">about-us</argument>
            <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">_blank</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink"   name="custom.link.account"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

After updating your code please do cache flush:

$ php bin/magento c:f